# Set Edit control text color and background color from within control's WndProc

Tags: windows, winapi

I have an Edit control subclass, and I want to set text color and background color in the control's WndProc.

I can't use WM_CTLCOLOREDIT since I don't have control over the parent's WndProc, and I prefer to avoid subclassing the parent window.

Is it possible?

Comment: Handling `WM_CTLCOLOREDIT` in the parent's `WndProc` is the correct solution. If you can't do that, then your subclass will have to handle `WM_PAINT` and `WM_ERASEBKGND` instead and completely draw the Edit control yourself.